# Anyone know any Shadowrun players?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I feel bad that the one question unanswered (even with a bounty) is the only Shadowrun question we've had. Is this game still played? Anyone know any active forums to go and recruit? I looked and found a few inactive ones but I didn't really look that hard.

Answer (score 1):

[Dumpshock](http://forums.dumpshock.com/) is the large active SR forum,
and at least when Catalyst was going through their whole financial scandal thing there was plenty of discussion on Fear the Boot, RPG.net, and theRPGSite.  It's still one of the more popular games.

Comment: Anyone ask them to come over answer our question?

Answer (score 1):

There's an official forum at http://www.shadowrun4.com/ as well.